# Partial image extent after clipping an image collection to a geometry in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, clip, land-cover

When clipping an image collection to a geometry in Google Earth Engine, the resulting clipped images only show a partial extent of the original image. What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that the clipped images cover the entire extent of the original image? I've already increased the time span but it does not work.

```
var startDate = '2015-01-01';
var endDate='2023-02-01';

var dw=ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
        .filterDate(startDate,endDate)
        .filterBounds(AOI);

var dwImage=ee.Image(dw.mosaic()).clip(AOI);
print ('DW ee.Image',dwImage);

var classification = dwImage.select('label');
var dwVisParams = {
  min:0, max:8,
  palette:['419BDF', '397D49', '88B053', '7A87C6',
    'E49635', 'DFC35A', 'C4281B', 'A59B8F',
    'B39FE1']
};

Map.addLayer(classification, dwVisParams, 'Classified Image');
```

[image]